# Iphone URL loading in tableview doubts

Tags: iphone

My requirement is, I have a main url. It contains multiple urls. I have to display multiple url in a tableview, with the main contents in it including a image. Like facebook status button. If we entered a link in the status textfiled it displays main content of that url.

Comment: please take some more effort into your questions. It really helps getting the answer you need.

Comment: Does 'main url containing multiple urls` mean a view with multiple urls?

Comment: i just want to load url in tableview,but not the full content ,just have to display the main content,like the facebook status button provide,when we insert a url in satus textbar,it displays the main content.like that

Comment: @Deepak yes view with multiple url,but i just want to knw how can i use facebook like functionality in my project,,i alredy mention above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you have to do is "Parse the HTML" and extract the elements you wish to display :)

Now when it comes to parsing..i would say it will be better if you have a XML data..

coz somehow extracting elements from HTML is bit painful.

for more help..check out this link..

[url loading in tableViews](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=754964)

happy coding :)

Comment: @sherry i download the code but nothing happens when i run the code,,but no errors